# How to read the attachment file from a mail in WSO2?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

How I can get the attachment from a mail in WSO2 ? I able to get the subject and body of the mail. I need to fetch an attachment file in the mail. How it could be done ? I'm using Gmail POP3 server.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing specific whether the mail is from some WSO2 server or not. If you have attachments, that implies the mail uses multipart/form. Therefore you can process it as a multipart/form message. There are a lot of libraries that you can use to do the parsing. e.g. Apache Commons, Javamail or you can use normal java URL connection and carefully work with the mime boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

We used to parse the whole message body looking for boundries of attachments, then apply Base64Decode to substracted pieces, then operate with them like binaries.
Sorry, I do not have that synapse-config right now, can not tell you exactly what to do.